# How can I change the Welcome email?

Tags: wss-3.0, email, permissions

I'm using WSS 3.0 and would like to change the welcome email that gets sent to users when they are first set up and when they are assigned permissions to a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is possible to customize some of those things globally in the farm, it is generally a bad idea.  I normally recommend that site owners send a note from their own email address anyway rather than coming from an unmonitored system account.

Comment: Why do you consider it a bad idea?  

The email that gets sent automatically at the moment says "click the link" but the link doesn't work and some of the terminology in the default email needs to be tailored for our specific needs.

Our system account routes inbound messages back to me so we don't have a problem on that score.

Thanks for your feedback and answers.

Comment: System customization settings like the welcome email may be updated as part of a Service Pack or upgrade.  In addition, those customizations would need to be kept up to date on each of the servers.